# How can I improve performance svg dragging while hit testing?

Tags: svg, drag-and-drop, draggable

I've got a class which makes an SVG element draggable. I want to adjust this class to prevent the draggable element from being dragged outside of a "container" (which is just another svg element). I've made the adjustment, and it works, but now it is much slower. Is there any way to improve the performance of this? I am targeting Firefox. And the container shape could also be a complex path.

Class to make an element draggable

```
function SVGDragClass(elementToDrag, elementToConstrain) {
    this.element = elementToDrag;
    this.container = elementToConstrain;
    ...snip
    function getPoint(e) {
        ...snip
        return ({
             x: //point of mouse adjusted for any existing matrixes
            ,y: //
        });
    }
    function setPoint(e) {
        ...snip
        //sets matrix of element (this.element) adjusting for matrixes
    }
    function onMouseMove(e) { //fires on mousemove event
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
        if( this.isDragging ) { //isDragging = true if the user is dragging the shape
            var point = getPoint(e);

            ////////////////////
            // Start of Question ----->
            ////////////////////
            this.element.style.display = "none";
            var mouseOverElement = document.elementFromPoint(point.x, point.y);
            if( this.container === mouseOverElement ) { // this.container is the object that the dragged item must be on top of
                setPoint(point);
            }
            this.element.style.display = "block";
            ////////////////////
            // <----- End of Question
            ////////////////////

        }
    }
    ...snip
}
```

Svg file to show what I'm trying to drag

```
<svg>
    <path id="container" ... />
    <circ id="dragMe" ... />
</svg>
```

Code that implements the class

```
function onLoad() {
    var draggable = new SVGDragClass( document.getElemenyById("dragMe"), document.getElemenyById("container") );
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking if the dragged element is still inside the container on every mouse move, have you thought about listening for the mouse pointer to actually hit the container's perimeter? For your **container** you could set `pointer-events:stroke` and register an event handler for `mouseenter` when dragging starts, i.e. when the mouse pointer is inside of the container. This event will fire once the mouse pointer hits the stroke of the container just before leaving it.

Comment: One possible alternative would be to render your container path to a Canvas (either at load or at start of drag), and then do your inside-the-path test by checking pixel colour.

Comment: altocumulus: that is genius. So far it seemed to be much slower (probably my fault) but I think the concept is sound.

Comment: Paul LeBeau: Thanks another solution, I'm wanting to stick with SVG, I was aware of this. It would be interesting to see a speed comparison though. It may be that I will be forced to go to canvas if I can get the speed worked out.

Comment: StackOverflow community: there are two perfectly good answers here. Yet these users know better than to answer the question because a tiny group of tyrant nerds with a lot of points will down vote them into oblivion. It's sad to see StackOverflow come to this end.